# onselectedindexchanged in a drop down list on the same item is called only client side?

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, updatepanel

I have an update panel :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upAppartiene" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddAppartiene" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="ddAppartiene_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Text="---" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Value 1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Value 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When I select each time a different value, all is ok : it call the context on server side, page load, and ddAppartiene_SelectedIndexChanged() method.

But, if I click on a value, than I re-click on the same value, it do the call to the server (Page Load is called) but the method ddAppartiene_SelectedIndexChanged() it is not called.

So, onselectedindexchanged works on client side, but on server side not? I don't think so...

Where am I wrong?

Comment: so no way to do this? .NET bug?

Answer (score 4):

I'm just a newbie but doesn't onselectedindexchanged event only fire when the selected index is actually changed? If you re-click the same value there is no change so the event doesn't fire.

Comment: set AutoPostBack to false and you won't get the PostBack Event anymore. However this is independent to the selectedindexchanged event

Comment: The event is fired on an index change. But if you click the same dropdown element there is no change, so that particular event does not work. Instead you could use a click event.

Comment: I know there is no change! But in fact (I repeat) an ajax request is called to the server! Try to add a `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` in the page load with an alert, or monitor the request! The event is fired...! A bug?

Comment: P.S. there isn't a `onclick` on `DropDownList`

Comment: that postback (pageload) is caused by your autopostback attribute. it makes the page do a refresh whenever you select a dropdown entry. try autopostback="false"

Answer (score 1):

Just like the event name says "SelectedIndexChanged", the index needs to change before it is fired. When you click the same item twice, the index is still the same as the previous and therefore has not changed. At this point, I think it is just a clicked and not changed.

What I do to avoid that is to actually provide an OK button. Whenever you click the button, the selected value is always picked, changed or not.

Comment: Yeah, it is just "clicked" and not "changed"; so why the event on client side is fired?

Comment: As said, the previous index and the current index are compared - if there is no difference, nothing happens

Comment: No :) Try! A request is fired to the server, also if I click on the same listitem in the DropDown :)